# how can i create a program that will display that a given point lies on the following conditions?

Tags: swift, tuples, control-flow

how can i create a program that will display that a given point lies on the following conditions?

conditions:

- origin
- red square box
- diagonal blue line
- first quadrant (I)
- second quadrant (I)
- third quadrant (I)
- fourth quadrant (I)

here is my working code:

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
case (0, 0):
    print("\(somePoint) is at the origin")
case (_, 0):
    print("\(somePoint) is on the x-axis")
case (0, _):
    print("\(somePoint) is on the y-axis")
case (-2...2, -2...2):
    print("\(somePoint) is inside the box")
default:
    print("\(somePoint) is outside of the box")
}
let anotherPoint = (2, 0)
switch anotherPoint {
case (let x, 0):
    print("on the x-axis with an x value of \(x)")
case (0, let y):
    print("on the y-axis with a y value of \(y)")
case let (x, y):
    print("somewhere else at (\(x), \(y))")
}
let yetAnotherPoint = (1, -1)
switch yetAnotherPoint {
case let (x, y) where x == y:
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == y")
case let (x, y) where x == -y:
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == -y")
case let (x, y):
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is just some arbitrary point")
}
```

[image]

Comment: is that blue line supposed to go through (0,0)?

Comment: i dont think so...

Answer (score 0):

```
func findQuadrant(point : CGPoint) {
    
    if point.x == 0 && point.y == 0{
        print("origin")
        
    }else if point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0{
        print("1 st quadrant")
        
    }else if point.x <= 0 && point.y >= 0{
        print("2 nd quadrant")
        
    }else if point.x <= 0 && point.y <= 0{
        print("3 rd quadrant")
        
    }else if point.x >= 0 && point.y <= 0{
        print("4 th quadrant")
    }
}

struct Square {
    var topLeftCorner : CGPoint
    var bottomRightCorner : CGPoint
}

func isInsideBox(point : CGPoint, square : Square) -> Bool{
    return (point.x < square.bottomRightCorner.x && point.x > square.topLeftCorner.x) &&
    (point.y < square.topLeftCorner.y && point.y > square.bottomRightCorner.y)
}

//point1 and point2 are the already known points on the line
func isOnLine(point1 : CGPoint, point2 : CGPoint, pointUWantToCheck : CGPoint) -> Bool{
    let gradient1 = atan2((point1.y - point2.y), (point1.x - point2.x))
    let gradient2 = atan2((point1.y - pointUWantToCheck.y), (point1.x - pointUWantToCheck.x))
    return gradient1 == gradient2
}
```